# Could I have some help fixing a vb XNA struct to handle Position, Color and normal. Example inside

Tags: c#, vb.net, struct, xna

This is more an issue of translating some c# documentation and syntax into visual basic stuff. I am writing in Visual basic, and using the 4.0 XNA refresh platform.

I am following a c# tutorial over [Riemers.net](http://www.riemers.net/eng/Tutorials/XNA/Csharp/Series1/Lighting_basics.php) but have had some difficulty reproducing his structure for handling Vertices, positions, colours and normals. I've been able to run the program fine using the prebuilt- VertexPositionColor & .VertexDeclaration.

The C# code for this problem is this:

```
 public struct VertexPositionColorNormal
 {            
     public Vector3 Position;
     public Color Color;
     public Vector3 Normal;

     public readonly static VertexDeclaration VertexDeclaration = new VertexDeclaration
     (
         new VertexElement(0, VertexElementFormat.Vector3, VertexElementUsage.Position, 0),
         new VertexElement(sizeof(float) * 3, VertexElementFormat.Color, VertexElementUsage.Color, 0),
         new VertexElement(sizeof(float) * 3 + 4, VertexElementFormat.Vector3, VertexElementUsage.Normal, 0)
     );
 }
```

And this is my attempt at the conversion

```
Public Structure VertexPositionColorNormal

Public Position As Vector3
Public Color As Color
Public Normal As Vector3

Public Shared SizeInBytes As Integer = 7 * 4

Public Shared ReadOnly VertexDeclaration As VertexElement() = New VertexElement() _
{New VertexElement(0, VertexElementFormat.Vector3, VertexElementUsage.Position, 0), _
New VertexElement(4 * 3, VertexElementFormat.Color, VertexElementUsage.Color, 0), _
New VertexElement(4 * 4, VertexElementFormat.Vector3, VertexElementUsage.Normal,                 0)}

End Structure
```

Whilst my attempt seems syntactically correct, it produces an error on this line:

```
GraphicsDevice.DrawUserIndexedPrimitives(PrimitiveType.TriangleList, vertices, 0, vertices.Length, indices, 0, indices.Length / 3, VertexPositionColorNormal.VertexDeclaration)
```

And gives me the following description of the error:

> Error 18
>   Overload resolution failed because no accessible 'DrawUserIndexedPrimitives' can be called with these arguments:
>
> 'Public Sub DrawUserIndexedPrimitives(Of VertexPositionColorNormal)(primitiveType As
>   Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics.PrimitiveType, vertexData() As
>   VertexPositionColorNormal, vertexOffset As Integer, numVertices As
>   Integer, indexData() As Short, indexOffset As Integer, primitiveCount
>   As Integer, vertexDeclaration As
>   Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics.VertexDeclaration)': **Value of type
>   '1-dimensional array of Integer' cannot be converted to '1-dimensional
>   array of Short' because 'Integer' is not derived from 'Short'.**
>
> 'Public Sub DrawUserIndexedPrimitives(Of VertexPositionColorNormal)(primitiveType As
>   Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics.PrimitiveType, vertexData() As
>   VertexPositionColorNormal, vertexOffset As Integer, numVertices As
>   Integer, indexData() As Short, indexOffset As Integer, primitiveCount
>   As Integer, vertexDeclaration As
>   Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics.VertexDeclaration)': **Value of type
>   '1-dimensional array of
>   Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics.VertexElement' cannot be converted to
>   'Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics.VertexDeclaration'.**
>
> 'Public Sub DrawUserIndexedPrimitives(Of VertexPositionColorNormal)(primitiveType As
>   Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics.PrimitiveType, vertexData() As
>   VertexPositionColorNormal, vertexOffset As Integer, numVertices As
>   Integer, indexData() As Integer, indexOffset As Integer,
>   primitiveCount As Integer, vertexDeclaration As
>   Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics.VertexDeclaration)': **Value of type
>   '1-dimensional array of
>   Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics.VertexElement' cannot be converted to
>   'Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics.VertexDeclaration'.**
>
> C:\Users\Xheis-Overlord\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\Test_Terrains2\Test_Terrains2\Test_Terrains2\Game1.vb   416 13  Test_Terrains2

Answer (score 1):

I'm not well versed in VB, but based on the error messages, I think this line is partially at fault:

```
Public Shared ReadOnly VertexDeclaration As VertexElement() = New VertexElement() _
```

In the C# you've included, the type of the `VertexDeclaration` object is actually `VertexDeclaration`. However, in your VB, you're treating it as type `VertexElement` array.

Also, what is `indices`?

Here's a link to the MSDN article on [DrawUserIndexPrimitives](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.graphics.graphicsdevice.drawuserindexedprimitives.aspx) for reference. There are four overloads to this method that are all very similar. Double check your argument types.

Comment: Thankyou for that, that was the problem- and thankfully dave addressed it as well. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0):

The original is not an array, but in your conversion it's an array.  Try this:

```
 Public Structure VertexPositionColorNormal
     Public Position As Vector3
     Public Color As Color
     Public Normal As Vector3

     Public ReadOnly Shared VertexDeclaration As New VertexDeclaration( _
        New VertexElement(0, VertexElementFormat.Vector3, VertexElementUsage.Position, 0), _
        New VertexElement(Len(New Single) * 3, VertexElementFormat.Color, VertexElementUsage.Color, 0), _
        New VertexElement(Len(New Single) * 3 + 4, VertexElementFormat.Vector3, VertexElementUsage.Normal, 0))
 End Structure
```

Comment: That worked perfectly, thank you very much Dave. What exactly are we doing here. Are WE initialising the vertexDeclaration with the parameters or are we setting up what parameters to parse into the vertexDeclaration?

Comment: It looks like you are calling the constructor of VertexDeclaration which has 3 VertexElements as parameters.